# Azure Data Explorer dashboard automation

Tags: azure-data-explorer

Is there a way to automate ADX dashboard deployment? ARM/bicep/terraform? UI provide possibility to save created dashboard as json and upload it back manually but is there any automation options for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today it is not possible to automate ADX dashboards deployment.
We have on our backlog an item to provide apis to automate this process.

Comment: Is this still the case in 2024?